# Convert object into 2-d array but remove keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to convert the below this:

```
let JSON = [
    {1:"hello",2:"goodbye",3:"bonjour"},
    {4:"hello2",5:"goodbye2",6:"bonjour2"},
    {7:"hello3",8:"goodbye3",9:"bonjour3"},
    {10:"hello4",11:"goodbye4",12:"bonjour4"}
]
```

to this:

```
let arr = [
    ["hello","goodbye","bonjour"],
    ["hello2","goodbye2","bonjour2"],
    ["hello3","goodbye3","bonjour3"],
    ["hello4","goodbye4","bonjour4"]
]
```

I have tried:

```
var row1 = JSON.map(function(e) {
    return [ e.1, e.2, e.3];
});
var row2 = JSON.map(function(e) {
    return [ e.4, e.5, e.6];
});
var row3 = JSON.map(function(e) {
    return [ e.7, e.8, e.9];
});
var row4 = JSON.map(function(e) {
    return [ e.10, e.11, e.12];

let array = [row1,row2,row3,row4]
```

But cannot get anything working. I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
let JSON = [
  {1:"hello",2:"goodbye",3:"bonjour"},
  {4:"hello2",5:"goodbye2",6:"bonjour2"},
  {7:"hello3",8:"goodbye3",9:"bonjour3"},
  {10:"hello4",11:"goodbye4",12:"bonjour4"}
];

let arr = JSON.map(obj => {
  return Object.values(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard `for` loop to iterate the object key's and push the object values into an array(ordered) which you return, all within the callback of `Array.map`. Also, your problem is that Array.map works on every item of the array, not just one at a time. that is why your code doesn't work the way you expected.

```
let JSON = [
    {1:"hello",2:"goodbye",3:"bonjour"},
    {4:"hello2",5:"goodbye2",6:"bonjour2"},
    {7:"hello3",8:"goodbye3",9:"bonjour3"},
    {10:"hello4",11:"goodbye4",12:"bonjour4"}
]

const result = JSON.map(a=>{
    const b = [];
    for(var k in a){
        b.push(a[k]);
    }
    return b;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, it seems you could simply use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
let original = [
  {1:"hello",2:"goodbye",3:"bonjour"},
  {4:"hello2",5:"goodbye2",6:"bonjour2"},
  {7:"hello3",8:"goodbye3",9:"bonjour3"},
  {10:"hello4",11:"goodbye4",12:"bonjour4"}
]

var array = original.map(Object.values);

console.log(array);
```

This works because the order of elements in each object is the same as the order you want to achieve in the result array.

If you this is not always the case (e.g. you have `{12:"bonjour4",11:"goodbye4",10:"hello4"}` and you still want to return `["hello4","goodbye4","bonjour4"]`) you can sort entries by their keys first. For example:

```js
let original = [
  {1:"hello",2:"goodbye",3:"bonjour"},
  {4:"hello2",5:"goodbye2",6:"bonjour2"},
  {7:"hello3",8:"goodbye3",9:"bonjour3"},
  {12:"bonjour4",11:"goodbye4",10:"hello4"}
]

var array = original
  .map(obj => Object
    .entries(obj)
    .sort(([k1], [k2]) => k1 - k2)
    .map(([_, v]) => v));

console.log(array);
```

As a side note, I'd caution you against using the name `JSON` since this will hide the built-in [`JSON` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).